# Mobile Nav: Close all open entries

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, selectors-api

Look at my pen: https://codepen.io/QJan84/pen/NXVgop

I have a problem here and I am looking for a solid solution.
If a menu item *(only first level)* is open, all previously opened menu items should be closed beforehand. Only one menu item *(only first level)* should be active.

For all `ul` with the class `nm__lvl nm__lvl--expanded`, `nm__lvl--expanded` has to be exchanged for `nm__lvL--collapsed`. Right?!
It must also be ensured that only the closing transition is finished and then the current menu item is opened. Close and open should happen one after the other.
Finally the question, how could I improve my script? Is the performance of the script good? What can be improved?
I'm currently switching from jquery to ES6, which is not so easy.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5co3nLt3/7/) I've added a new function to your code that provides the feature you are looking for.

```
//[...]
let nextNode = ele.nextElementSibling,
    prevNode = ele.previousElementSibling;

hideOtherSubMenus(prevNode);
prevNode.classList.toggle("nm__lvl__entry--active");
// [...]
```

---

```
function hideOtherSubMenus(elem) {
    var parentUl = elem.parentElement.parentElement;
  var activeSiblings = parentUl.querySelectorAll(".nm__lvl__entry.nm__lvl__entry--active");

  for (var i = 0; i < activeSiblings.length; i++) {
    var sibling = activeSiblings[i]; console.log(sibling);
    var btn = sibling.nextElementSibling;

    btn.click();
  }
}
```

It's probably not the best solution but the best I came up with to solve your problem.